# Is it possible to run commands for the Magento in xampp from another device?

Tags: magento2.3, command-line, xampp

My colleague installed Magento in xampp on his system and I can browse the site frontend and backend on my system using his system IP.

Is it possible to develop and run commands in my system though he installed the Magento on his system?

Could anyone please guide me?

Answer (score 0):

If you can able to browse frontend by system IP(host) you can definitely connect by SSH.

Go to the terminal and try below commands

```
ssh username@host
```

When it prompts for password add the password and you can able to connect.

Comment: I can connect by SSH but not able to run commands

Comment: php bin/magento not works than you will need to find relative path where php exist and include full path for php.

Comment: How to find the relative path?

Comment: For example path like: /opt/lampp/bin/php bin/magento